# MySQL: Contraint for at least one of two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

My table is made of two columns: A and B, which are both nullable and are foreign keys from other tables. How can I impose a constraint that at least one of A or B should be not null?

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints at all.  [From the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."

Comment: Deleted the answer, I didn't realize you are using MySQL.

Comment: If they are foreign keys, does that mean that you have other tables that have nullable primary keys? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @FilipeSilva But the column in the referencing table need not be "not null" for it to be foreign-keyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Answer: please provide comments if there is a better solution.

I found [this](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2009/12/validating-mysql-data-entry-with_15.html) solution by Roland Bouman. Based on the spirit of his solution, here is what I have:

```
delimiter go

create procedure validateAtLeastOneValue(
    in a bigint(16), in b bigint(16)
)
deterministic
no sql
_main: begin
    declare err_no value_specified condition for sqlstate '45000';

    if a is not null then
        leave _main; -- nothing to validate
    end if;
    if b is not null then
        leave _main; -- nothing to validate
    end if;
    signal err_no_value_specified -- raise an error
    set message_text = 'No value specified';
end;
go

delimiter ;
```

Now invoke this procedure from an event handler for insert (or update) on the table.

```
create trigger on_before_insert
before insert on mytable
for each row
begin
    call validateAtLeastOneType(
        NEW.a
    ,   NEW.b 
    );
end;

create trigger on_before_update
before update on mytable
for each row
begin
    call validateAtLeastOneType(
        NEW.a
    ,   NEW.b 
    );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make A and B not null (but zero is ok) and add a unique key on the two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT AB UNIQUE (A,B)
```

Comment: But that would impose uniqueness on A B as a combination, correct? That is not what I want.

Comment: Correct, it's not ok if you want to have the same combination on multiple records.